# How to build css and js file into one js file

Tags: reactjs, widget, vite

`<div class="reddit_widget" checkout-type="popup" width="350"></div>`
`<link href="https://precious-biscuit-3e1ec3.netlify.app/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
`<script src="https://precious-biscuit-3e1ec3.netlify.app/index.js"></script>`
i tried building a widget and bundling it with parcel, i got two different files for both js and css.
but what i want it is just to have a single file for only js so i dont have to give users a css link

I have tried using parcel bundler, but I'll like to use libinjectcss from vite, it seems there's a way that works but I just cannot figure it out for my react app(I used vite to start the app)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.